# Optimizing my mysql query

Tags: php, mysql

I clearly know that there are plenty of questions already asked on this topic but i couldn't optimize mine.
So below is my query:

```
    select tc.id, tc.name tc, s.name state, d.name district, 
    count(distinct case when curdate() between b.starttime and b.endtime then b.id end) as active,
    (case when count(distinct case when curdate() between b.starttime and b.endtime then b.id end) > 0 then 'active' when tc.status = 'Archived-I' then 'transitioned' when count(distinct case when curdate() between b.starttime and b.endtime then b.id end) = 0 and tc.status != 'Archived-I' then 'Idle' end ) as _status,
    count(distinct(b.id)) as batches, sum(case when sb.status = 'active' then 1 else 0 end) as in_training, count(distinct case when sb.status = 'complete' then sb.student_id end) as trained,
    count(distinct(sa.student_id)) as assessed, count(distinct(sp.student_id)) as placed 
    from training_centers tc left join batches b on b.training_center_id = tc.id 
    left join student_batches sb on b.id = sb.batch_id 
    left join student_assessments sa on sa.batch_id = b.id 
    left join student_placements sp on sp.batch_id = b.id 
    left join states s on s.id = tc.state_id 
    left join districts d on d.id = tc.district_id 
    where tc.implementing_agency_id = 28 
    group by tc.id 
    order by tc.name
```

Output of EXPLAIN is below:

```
    id|select_type|table|type|possible_keys|key|key_len|ref|rows|Extra
    1|SIMPLE|tc|ref|implementing agency|implementing agency|4|const|201|Using temporary; Using filesort
    1|SIMPLE|b|ALL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|11018|
    1|SIMPLE|sb|ref|batch id|batch id|4|ministry_mis.b.id|10|
    1|SIMPLE|sa|ref|batch|batch|4|ministry_mis.b.id|7|
    1|SIMPLE|sp|ALL|NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|78799|
    1|SIMPLE|s|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|ministry_mis.tc.state_id|1|
    1|SIMPLE|d|eq_ref|PRIMARY|PRIMARY|4|ministry_mis.tc.district_id|1|1|
```

I have already tried query caching and since i am using this query in a php application, i have tried memcache as well.
Please help me understand, how can i optimize my query or if something is wrong here.

Comment: Using `group by` and `order by` is almost always a problem. Your explain shows Using temporary; Using filesort, which is always slow.

Comment: You can try to set temp dir for MySQL to /dev/shm (which is usually mounted over by tmpfs), so all filesystem operations caused by 'using temporary' will be in memory, not in a file on disk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add an appropriate index on the `students_placements` table (aliased as `sp` in the query).

```
CREATE INDEX student_placements_IX1
    ON student_placements (batch_id, student_id)
```

The EXPLAIN output is showing a full scan of that table, ("ALL"). With that index, we'd expect the EXPLAIN output to show a `ref` operation.

Also, on the `batches` table (aliased as `b` in the query) add an index like:

```
CREATE INDEX batches_IX1
    ON batches (training_center_id, id, starttime, endtime)
```

If all of the columns referenced in the query for a table come from the index, the index is called a "covering index" for the query, and the the `EXPLAIN` output will show "Using index" in the Extra column.

If `id` is a UNIQUE or PRIMARY KEY on the `training_centers` table (aliased as `tc` in the questy), you might also consider changing the query to do this:

```
 GROUP BY tc.name, tc.id
 ORDER BY tc.name
```

A covering index on `training_centers`, may also be of benefit:

```
CREATE INDEX training_centers_IX1
    ON training_centers (implementing_agency_id, name, id, state_id, district_id, status)
```

We'd need to look at the EXPLAIN after the indexes are added, and go from there. (Sometimes, MySQL can make use of an index to avoid a "Using filesort" operation, if an appropriate index is available.)

Comment: Thank you. Now my query is taking very less time compared to what it was taking earlier.. But it's still not good enough so can you suggest me other things also which i can do to speed up the query more?

Comment: Now i know why my EXPLAIN statement was showing Using Temporary and Using Filesort. So here is the [link](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/internal-temporary-tables.html) for people who are stuck like me .